# Firebase query with twice orderByChild condition

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem:

I would like to create a firebase query using twice the orderByChild() condition

**First condition:**  compare a field

**Second condition:**  order the elements by a specific field.

This is an example of the query that I would doing:

```
ref.orderByChild("id").equalTo("1").orderByChild("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Model m = d.getValue(Model.class);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

If I try to use this query the app gets crashed. It's possible to create this type of query in Firebase?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 4):

Multiple orderbychild() queries is not supported by firebase .

Look at these links to structure your database.

[Android firebase apply multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041385/android-firebase-apply-multiple-queries)

[Firebase how to set orderByChild more than one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43602666/firebase-how-to-set-orderbychild-more-than-one)

[Android Firebase multiple sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639877/android-firebase-multiple-sort)

[Query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase)

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to create this kind of query since you cannot use two `orderByChild()`, the below are possible:

```
orderByChild("name").equalTo(name);
orderByKey().equalTo("key_here");
orderByChild("name").limitToFirst(10)
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html

Comment: Damn. Don't exist any workaround for this problem?

Comment: nope there is no workaround, you need to change the database structure to make this work like you want, or use firestore for these kind of queries instead of firebase

Comment: Thank's man !!!!